# Can I use LINQ to check if objects in a list have a unique ID?

Tags: c#, linq, list, object

say I have a list containing objects like this one:

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name; 
    private string _id;
    private int _age;

    public Person 
    {
    }

    // Accessors
}

public class ManipulatePerson
{
    Person person = new Person();
    List<Person> personList = new List<Person>;

    // Assign values

    private void PopulateList();
    {
        // Loop 
        personList.Add(person);

        // Check if every Person has a unique ID
    }
}
```

and I wanted to check that each Person had a unique ID. I would like to return a boolean true/false depending on whether or not the IDs are unique. Is this something I can achieve with LINQ?

Comment: Use group by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: Or else, use `Distinct` and `Count` if the number differs. But firstly, put your ID to be a property rather than private field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that you can even leverage directly an `HashSet<>`:

```
var hs = new HashSet<string>();
bool areAllPeopleUnique = personList.All(x => hs.Add(x.Id));
```

(and is the code that I normally use)

It has the advantage that on the best case (presence of some duplicates) it will stop before analyzing all the `personList` collection.

Comment: Intersection, please! :D

Comment: This is fine, but even better would be to override the hashcode and then you could do it directly var hs = new HashSet<Person>();

Comment: @user853710 Or you could create a separate `IEqualityComparer<>` with the special `GetHashCode`.

Comment: true, both are valid thigs.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you could answer another question, continuing on from your original answer?

Answer (score 7):

I would use [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) and then check against the counts for example:

```
bool bAreAllPeopleUnique = (personList.Distinct(p => p.ID).Count == personList.Count);
```

However as @Ian commented you will need to add a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) to the `Person` class so that you can access the Id like so:

```
public string ID
{
    get { return _id; }
}
```

A 'nicer' way to implement this would be to add a method like so:

```
private bool AreAllPeopleUnique(IEnumerable<Person> people)
{
    return (personList.Distinct(p => p.ID).Count == personList.Count);
}
```

NOTE: The method takes in an `IEnumerable` not a list so that any class implementing that interface can use the method.

Answer (score 1):

One of best ways to do so is overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, and implementing `IEquatable<T>`:

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
     public string Id { get; set; }

     public override bool Equals(object some) => Equals(some as Person);
     public override bool GetHashCode() => Id != null ? Id.GetHashCode() : 0;
     public bool Equals(Person person) => person != null && person.UniqueId == UniqueId;
}
```

Now you can use `HashSet<T>` to store *unique objects* and it will be impossible that you store duplicates. And, in addition, if you try to add a duplicated item, `Add` will return `false`.

**NOTE: My `IEquatable<T>`, and `Equals`/`GetHashCode` overrides are very basic, but this sample implementation should give you a good hint on how to elegantly handle your scenario.**

You can check this Q&A to get an idea on how to implement `GetHashCode` [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Maybe this other Q&A might be interesitng for you: [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` for getting unique items:

```
var result = personList.GroupBy(p=> p.Id)
                   .Select(grp => grp.First())
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: You can use the aggregation Key. On 100 K records it is a significant improvement
Select(grp => grp.Key)